# Perl - multiply decimal

Tags: perl, multiplication

When the results come out, it gives the wrong results if I multiply it by (0.62). But if I multiply it by a whole number (1 or 2 ) is okay. How do I do decimal multiplication?

```
Input
*****

HEADER
  GAME
     BALL X1 ;
     GOOD CATCH 1 5.6770 4.550 3.455 2.333 ;
     END
END

Output
******
HEADER
  GAME
     BALL X1 ;
     GOOD CATCH 1 3.5197.4 2.821 2.1421 1.4464.6 ;
     END
END


use strict ;

sub multiply {
    my ( $str ) = @_;

    $str =~ s/(GOOD CATCH.*?;)/_multiply($1)/ge;
    return $str;
}

sub _multiply {
    my ( $str ) = @_;

    $str =~ s/(\d\d+)/_mul_number($1)/ge;
    return $str;
}

sub _mul_number {
    my ($num) = @_;

    return $num * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression `$str =~ s/(\d\d+)/_mul_number($1)/ge;` looks for `(\d\d+)` which will match a sequence of two or more digits, but not a decimal point. With decimal numbers, it will treat them as two separate numbers; for instance, given "12.34", it will separately process "12" and "34", giving "7.44" and "21.08", for a final result of "7.44.21.08". Which is probably not what you want.

In order to handle decimal numbers in the input, you'll need to expand the regular expression to match them. A simple possibility would be `([\d.]+)`, that is: `$str =~ s/([\d.]+)/_mul_number($1)/ge;`

A more complex regex could also make sure there's at most one decimal point (to reject "12.34.56") or allow `+` and/or `-` signs for positive and negative numbers.

Comment: I got the correct results now with the s/([d.]+)/_mul_number but how do I not skip the first digit? I do not want the 1st digit number to be multiplied. It should start from 2nd to 4th digit.

Comment: Right, that's probably easiest done in the `multiply` function; change `s/(GOOD CATCH.*?;)/_multiply($1)/ge` to `s/(GOOD CATCH\s+\d+)(.*?;)/$1_multiply($2)/ge` so the first number is never passed through into `_multiply`. If it gets much more complicated than that, though, you'll probably want to split that up into several lines, first breaking apart the line into several variables, then handling each of the variables separately.